# Помогите, пожалуйста, как в React js как сделать разворачивающееся дерево из ul li ? Как на скриншоте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, дерево

Помогите, пожалуйста, как в React js как сделать разворачивающееся дерево из ul li ? Как на скриншоте?

[image: Дерево ul li]

Comment: а вы сами пробовали как-то сделать?

Comment: даже не знаю с чего начать.... в html + js + css примеры в сети есть, а вот как это все оформить в компонент реакта не знаю.

Comment: может тогда лучше сначала основы почитать?